# Google+ Auth error google_too_many_active_tokens

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I have a web server that uses the Google OAuth 2.0 interface to retrieve access and refresh tokens to perform G+ data retrievals (Java).

I noticed that a particular user got a TokenResponseException when our server made the GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest call.  The error was 400 google_too_many_active_tokens.

Can I get clarification on what this error means and what limits there are?  Is this limit apply to the client (our application) level or our client level?

Thank you!

Comment: If I have answered your question in a satisfactory way I would love it if you would accept my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Google apparently will not comment on how many is too many. As for things you can do to rectify the situation, you can go and release several of your active tokens. [This article](http://www.dainbinder.com/2013/05/having-google-login-problems-android.html) goes through that process in detail.